# Hyperwallet API, remove a user / a transfer method

Tags: api

My problem is that on my development system, I flushed all my users, and now I don't have the hyperwallet user's id. I could retrieve it from hyperwallet API and put in back in place. But what if I want to recreate the user's hyperwallet account?

The error is "DUPLICATE_EMAIL_REGISTRATION" and I couldn't find a single way of removing the user from hyperwallet.

This is the same for the transfer method which state "DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_CREATION" but I do not have, nor in the API, nor in the sandbox interface, the possibility to remove transfer method.

How do you achieve this ? I'd like to not create a new sandbox account just to start from scratch because once in production, I won't be able to resolve this problem.

EDIT :

The whole documentation doesn't contain a single mention of the possibility to delete an account nor to create a new account with the same email.
Also users contains an attribute "Status" but the "Update user" section doesn't mention possibility to update the said status, and the "status transition" chapter only allow to change the "status" for bank accounts/prepaid card account/paypal account etc. But it doesn't seem possible to change de status of the user itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the issue, we're actually in the process of rolling out this documentation.

There are 2 ways of solving this:
1) we can close existing accounts for you, so you are able to recreate them
2) we can provide you with a report of existing accounts, so you can backfill your system. Accounts in our system have your reference id (clientUserId) as well as ours (token).

Please contact our Developer Support (devsupport@hyperwallet.com) and please reference to me and add a reference to your question here. We'll be happy to assist you.

Thank you,
Willem

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So this is the intended behavior not to be able to set the status of a user to `de_activate` by ourselves? Or it will be implemented later? Also, if a user of my application remove his account and subscribe again I need to retrieve his hyperwallet user token (since email can't be duplicated). As far as I've digged in, I can't search a user by email but I can retrieve his user token from the error string I get when trying to create a new user token with the same email. Is their a better approach?

Comment: I'll be happy to contact the developer support if needed, but I prefer to get as much information as possible here so other users of this website can also find answers if needed.

Comment: @Willem i am facing some issues while creating hyperwallet accounts i am getting {"error":"INCORRECT_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS"} can anybody please help?